# java gui if else does no work with arraylist

Tags: java, swing

My code with java GUI adds to an arraylist from a file.txt I have in a button the code that compares the code introduced in a textfield with the position in the araylist with an if else. But enter what you enter always goes through the else never through the if.

If I add the components manually as in `Arraylist ArrayList <String> answer = new ArrayList <String> ();`
then if else works.

But it seems that if I compare the text of the textfield with the 
 `ArrayList <String> answer1 = new ArrayList <String> ();`, the if does not work does not do well the comparison

The question is that I need to ask the user 266 questions The user must enter the answers, if the answer is not correct, an incorrect reply message should come out
but I can not get the if else to work with an arraylist loaded with a file.text here is my code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class question_answer extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnAnswer;
    private JLabel lblNewLabelcuestion;
    private JLabel LabelTextF;
    private JLabel labelArraylistPos;
    private JLabel lblNewLabelTF;
    private JLabel lblNewLabelAL;
    static int count = 0;

    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private static JTextArea textArea;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    question_answer frame = new question_answer();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public question_answer() {
        File archive = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        //This works
        /*
         * ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
         * question.add("What is your name?");
         * question.add("What is your surname?");
         * question.add("What is your age?");
         * ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
         * answer.add("Pedro"); 
         * answer.add("Rodriguez");
         * answer.add("46");
         */

        ArrayList<String> answer1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            archive = new File("C:\\answer.txt");
            String line;
            fr = new FileReader(archive);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer1.add(line);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 567, 400);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        lblNewLabelcuestion = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabelcuestion.setBounds(60, 56, 360, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabelcuestion);

        lblNewLabelTF = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabelTF.setBounds(60, 292, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabelTF);

        LabelTextF = new JLabel("TextField");
        LabelTextF.setBounds(60, 263, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(LabelTextF);

        lblNewLabelAL = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabelAL.setBounds(170, 292, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabelAL);

        labelArraylistPos = new JLabel("Arraylist Position");
        labelArraylistPos.setBounds(170, 263, 110, 16);
        contentPane.add(labelArraylistPos);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(340, 139, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        lblNewLabelcuestion.setText(answer1.get(count));
        btnAnswer = new JButton("answer");

        lblNewLabelAL.setText(answer1.get(count));

        btnAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String line1;
                for (int j = 0; j < answer1.size(); j++) {
                    line1 = answer1.get(j);
                    textArea.append(line1);
                }

                lblNewLabelcuestion.setText(answer1.get(count));
                lblNewLabelAL.setText(answer1.get(count));
                lblNewLabelTF.setText(textField.getText());

                String c = answer1.get(count);
                String Tf = textField.getText();

                if (Tf.equals(c)) {
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText("Good");
                } else {
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText("Wrong");
                }
                count += 1;
            }
        });
        btnAnswer.setBounds(340, 198, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnAnswer);

        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(45, 153, 256, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(345, 273, 181, 67);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("achive.text  content");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(340, 244, 116, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    }

}
`
```

Comment: 1. Use a debugger to trace the flow of code and to check the state of your variables when the critical code is run (add a break point within the ActionListener). 2. If still stuck, you should consider refactoring this code so that the logical portions (the model) and the GUI portions (the view) are separate and separately testable. This will make for easier debugging by both you and us.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: If still stuck, consider creating and posting a valid [mcve], code that we can compile, run and test. Again, doing point 2) above, refactoring your code into separately testable units, will make it much easier for you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In any text editor, when you press enter, the the editor enters what is called a line break. This character is invisible but it tells the editor where to make a new line. You need to remove these characters from your lines. Good news is you only have to add one line of code to achieve this! Where you have:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    answer1.add(line);
}
```

Replace it with:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), “”);
    answer1.add(line);
}
```

The above code will replace any line separator defined by the OS with an empty string, thereby making your compared strings equal.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was  `String c = answer1.get(count).trim();`